# Is the polar curve $\theta=k$ for some constant $k$ a ray or a line?

Tags: analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

I've seen both interpretations of the polar equation $\theta=k$. Does this depend on whether we allow $r<0$ or not?

Comment: DESMOS draws the "ray" to both sides,

Comment: Polar coordinates have its variables $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $r \in [0,\infty)$, which means $r$ cannot be below zero. Any positive $r$ satisfies the equation $\theta=k$ so it's a ray

Comment: @JohnK Do you have any textbook reference for that?

Comment: @imranfat [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Polar_coordinates)

Comment: @JohnK You have done your homework. The point I was making is, that the choice whether or not $r$ can be negative is arbitrary. In case of limacons, if you take out negative $r$'s then part of the graph won't be displayed. So for the purpose of calculus (like areas of polar curves), it is perfectly OK to have negative $r$'s. (Stewart Calculus, Larson Calculus, etc).

Comment: Yes, it depends on the precise definition.  Both interpretations exist. A polar rose will allow negative $r$.  Unique polar co-ordinated will usually not do so.

Comment: The heavy machinery of Complex Analysis is based on the idea that any non-zero complex number $z$ can be uniquely expressed as $re^{i\theta} = r[\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)],$ where it is understood that the designation of $\theta$ is only considered unique within a modulus of $(2 \pi)$ and where $0 < r \in \mathbb{R}.$  Complex Analysis makes strong use of the uniqueness of the variables $r, \theta$.